# REST API - SAML Authentication with Azure AD as IDP

Tags: authentication, jmeter, saml-2.0, rest-assured, spring-saml

Having application with SAML authentication along with Azure AD as IDP. When I hit Login SSO button the following happens:

1. Hits SAML Redirect URL (/Saml/SAMLLoginRedirect)
2. Redirects automatically to Ping Federator. Redirected URL is received with the response header of the first request. URL consist some SAMLRequest Token and RelayState value. Final response has Submit Form along with new SAMLRequest token and RelayState.
3. Hitting IDP (login.microsoftonline.com//saml2 with the SAMLRequest and RelayState from the final response not works as expected.

I have resolved this issue in jmeter. I have just enabled Follow Redirect so jmeter provides the response and cookie. I am extracting the Header value of first the request from URL. It is just because Jmeter has the feature of accumulating redirect sample into the original request.

4. So I am again hitting Ping Federator with the Token and RelayState received using URL extractor along with final response Cookie.

Further I am able to complete the IDP process successfully.

I am not able to achieve the same using RestAssured. When I disable redirect I am able to get the url from header. Processing the URL from the header value throws 500 error code though I have added the cookie information.

If I enabled redirect I am getting 200 response code along with expected response body and cookie.

But I am unable to proceed to the Ping Federator with the token and relay state received from the response. So I have to hit again the Ping Federator with the previous SAML Token again as I did with jMeter to achieve the proper response.

Problem: Unable to get the header value if I enable the redirect and further processing fails. If I disable the redirect then I am not getting Cookie and expected response when processing the URL from header value. Here all are GET request until the IDP (login.microsoftonline.com)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) automatically extracts cookies from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header and sends them with the next request via [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) request header if domain and path match and the cookie isn't expired.

RestAssured doesn't do this automatically so you will need to extract the cookies from the response and add them to the next request manually.

References:

- [REST Assured Tutorial 49 – How To Retrieve Single and MultiValue Headers From Response Using Rest Assured](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2020/09/29/rest-assured-tutorial-49-how-to-retrieve-single-and-multivalue-headers-from-response-using-rest-assured/)
- [Headers, Cookies and Parameters with REST-assured](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-header-cookie-parameter)

Going forward you can just use a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to compare requests coming from JMeter and RestAssured, given you send the same request (apart from dynamic parameteres which need to be correlated) you will get the same response

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. I just missed out to share earlier. Actually, I have added cookie too while hitting IDP with the redirected response. Thats what the actual problem. I am not getting the cookie when I disable the redirect.



Note that I am getting cookies only when I enabled the redirect. When I disabled the redirect and processing the URL received from the response header, which is not working as expected and responds back with 500 error code.